# I got problem with the length of dataframe while using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

```
a=0
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    if df['column name'][i][7]!='1' or df['column name'][i][7]='6':
        a=a+1
```

If i run this piece of code, I got error "string index out of range". Can someone help me to solve this problem.
P.S. df has about 10 million rows

Comment: Could you please explain why you have a 7? Unless i am mistaken the format for arrays should be array[column][row] but what is the last part meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

If the index is greater or equal to the length of the string then this error occurs.

You can have a check whether the string is equal or more than `7` characters.

```
a=0
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    data = df['column name'][i]
    if len(data) > 6 and (data[7] != '1' or data[7] == '6'):
        a=a+1
```

you can do this by list comprehension

```
can_count = lambda row: len(row['col']) > 6 and (row['col'][7] != '1' or row['col'][7] == '6')
a = sum((1 for _, row in df.iterrows() if can_count(row)))
```

One thing to note is `df['column name'][i][7]='6'` should be `==` not `=`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the assignment operator '=' in your code instead of '==' . I have copy pasted the line to indicate this. Can you retry and indicate the error message you finally get. Also, a little more comment on what you would like to achieve with the operation.

```
    if df['column name'][i][7]!='1' or df['column name'][i][7]='6':
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please add an example for your string? your data is probably too short.

if you use this: df['column name'][i][7], your string should be at least 8 charas long.

good luck

Comment: also, you should change the '=' to '=='

Comment: Welcome Maria, is this different from [Praveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63334249/6692898) ?

Comment: @RichieV in  Praveen's code It seems that the code should be longer than 6 characters (and not 7)